# ChangeListener for all RealmObjects in a list

Tags: android, realm

Suppose I have a `RealmObject` like this.

```
public class DownloadQueue extends RealmObject {
    public RealmList<Download> queue;
}
```

If a add a `ChangeListener` to this object, will I get notified when items are added or changed? Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to listen to changes among the `Download` realm objects, then you'll need to add a `RealmChangeListener` to a `RealmResults` that belongs to the `Download` class.

```
// field variable
RealmChangeListener<RealmResults<Download>> realmChangeListener = new RealmChangeListener<RealmResults<Download>>() {
    @Override
    public void onChange(RealmResults<Download> results) {
        // change happened
    }
};

// field variable;
RealmResults<Download> resultSet;

//...
resultSet = realm.where(Download.class).findAll();
resultSet.addChangeListener(realmChangeListener);
```